# Power BI throws Error: Access to the path when I exit it in Windows

Tags: windows, powerbi

Each time I close Power BI on Win 7 I get the error below.
I, by default, launch Power BI with Admin permission and tried everything to stop this non-fatal error from recurring.

OS: Windows 7 64 bit
Software: Power Bi platform - the newest version

Is there a way to stop this error messages from recurring?

thanks

*Error:*

```
Feedback Type:
Frown (Error)
Error Message:
Error: Access to the path 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\temp.User.zip' is denied.
File 'User.zip' snapshot:
    FullName: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\User.zip'
    IsReadonly: False
    IsHidden: False
File 'temp.User.zip' snapshot:
    FullName: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\temp.User.zip'
    IsReadonly: False
    IsHidden: False
Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Storage.Local.SharedLocalStorageAccessor.CopyStreamToFile()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Storage.Local.SharedLocalStorageAccessor.EnsureFolderCreated(Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Storage.Local.SharedLocalStorageAccessor.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Access>b__0(SharedLocalStorage sharedLocalStorage)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Storage.Local.SharedLocalStorageAccessor.SharedLocalStorage.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Storage.Local.LocalUISettingsStorage.SetSettings(MetadataSet metadataSet)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.Storage.TracingUISettingsStorage.SetSettings(MetadataSet metadataSet)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.Ribbon.EditorRibbonControlBase.Dispose()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
Stack Trace Message:
Error: Access to the path 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\temp.User.zip' is denied.
File 'User.zip' snapshot:
    FullName: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\User.zip'
    IsReadonly: False
    IsHidden: False
File 'temp.User.zip' snapshot:
    FullName: 'C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\temp.User.zip'
    IsReadonly: False
    IsHidden: False
Invocation Stack Trace:
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionExtensions.GetCurrentInvocationStackTrace()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.StackTraceInfo..ctor(String exceptionStackTrace, String invocationStackTrace, String exceptionMessage)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Telemetry.PowerBIUserFeedbackServices.ReportException(IWindowHandle activeWindow, IUIHost uiHost, FeedbackPackageInfo feedbackPackageInfo, Exception e, Boolean useGDICapture)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass1.<HandleException>b__0()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.SynchronizationContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass3.<SendAndMarshalExceptions>b__0(Object null)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackDo(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbackHelper(Object obj)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallback(ThreadMethodEntry tme)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.InvokeMarshaledCallbacks()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.UnexpectedExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.Utilities.UIBlockingAwareExceptionHandler.HandleException(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.EditorDialogBase.OnWindowDestroyed()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.DialogWindowBase.OnHandleDestroyed(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmDestroy(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Windows.WebDialogWindow.WndProc(Message& message)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.MainWindow.MainWebDialogWindow.WndProc(Message& message)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntDestroyWindow(HandleRef hWnd)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IntDestroyWindow(HandleRef hWnd)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DestroyHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.DestroyHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.WebDialogs.WebDialogBase`1.ShowModal(IWindowHandle owner)
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Client.UI.Shared.WindowManager.ShowModal[T](T dialog, Func`1 showModalFunction)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.<>c__DisplayClass10.<Main>b__0()
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Windows.IExceptionHandlerExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass7.<HandleExceptionsWithNestedTasks>b__6()
   at Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)
   at Microsoft.PowerBI.Client.Program.Main(String[] args)
Model Default Mode:
Empty
Snapshot Trace Logs:
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\FrownSnapShot1617141224.zip
Performance Trace Logs:
C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Power BI Desktop\PerformanceTraces.zip
Disabled Preview Features:
PBI_shapeMapVisualEnabled
MIntellisense
PBI_newFromWeb
PBI_SpanishLinguisticsEnabled
CustomConnectors
PBI_PdfImport
PBI_variationUIChange
PBI_PythonSupportEnabled
PBI_showIncrementalRefreshPolicy
PBI_compositeModels
PBI_DB2DQ
PBI_showManageAggregations
Disabled DirectQuery Options:
PBI_DirectQuery_Unrestricted
TreatHanaAsRelationalSource
Cloud:
GlobalCloud
Formulas:
section Section1;*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an environmental issue and is usually due to a Virus Checker.
In my case it was Avira.
When possible, re-configuring anti-Virus software would be the way to resolve it. If one's anti-virus cannot be adequately re-configured, installing a different one would be another option.
Kaspersky does not seem to cause this issue.